# It ____ that the Moricans _____ certain plants in nature as medicine

Tags: grammar, causatives

It ____ that the Moricans _____ certain plants in nature as medicine.

**My answer was:** is known / are using

**Correct answer is:** was known / had used

Could you explain me why is my answer was wrong and the other one is correct.

Thank you

Comment: They both seem correct. Do you have more context? Was the previous question also about the Moricans? Or does this question stand alone? (By the way, do you mean Mohicans?)

Comment: Both are grammatically correct - the difference is tense! You should really research this more yourself. Look up the words in the dictionary and know the difference.

Comment: There is no more context. Since everyone says both of them correct, I guess the problem is the moricans must have been exist in the past but not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Moricans are a group that existed in the past, you must use some form of the past tense to describe them.

> It was known that the Moricans **had used** certain plants in nature as medicine.

"It was known" could just as easily be "It is known", depending on the context.

Your answer could be correct if the Moricans still exist and are currently using plants as medicine and you're talking about them in the present.
Otherwise you need to use the past tense to describe them.

Comment: Thank you. Others said that both are correct and a context is needed. However this was a question in an exercise paper and there is no more Info about this question. So, your answer is the correct I guess. Moracians must have been exist in the past

Comment: YW. BTW, are you sure it's not Mohicans?

Comment: It was written as Moricans but it must be a spelling mistake in the book.

Comment: If a the book can't even get simple spelling like "Mohican" correct, then I suggest you find a different book!